# Exponential Term in Spline Polynomial

Tags: exponential-function, spline

Need some help here.

A cubic spline takes the form of:

$a + b^t + ct^2 + dt^3$

Is there such a spline that incorporates an exponential term to take the form of:

$a + bt + ct^2 + dt^3 + fe^{Xt}$

where $X$ is just some constant?

Thanks!

Grant

Comment: In principle you can use any linearly independent basis functions to approximate or interpolate a function.  The term "spline" is usually reserved for polynomials, though.
What do really want to know about these functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some "spline under tension" curves that use exponential functions (hyperbolic sines and cosines, actually). They don't have exactly the form you described. When the tension parameter is set to zero, they reduce to conventional cubic splines. They are not widely used. [Here](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/360924.360974) is one reference. You'll find others if you search for "spline under tension".